# How to write a multivariable polynomial as a matrix expression

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Say I have a polynomial $2x^2 + 3xy + 9y^2$, I was wondering how I would go about converting this into a matrix expression of the form $(x,y)S$, where $S$ is a $1 \times 2 $ matrix.

Any help would be appreciated and I apologise for being unable to figure out how to put a matrix in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, since you have a quadratic polynomial, you need to have an expression where $(x,y)$ occurs *twice*, not once. Something like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you multiply this out and compare the coefficients to your expression?

Answer (score 1):

$$2x^2 + 3xy + 9y^2 = (x,y)\begin{pmatrix}2&\frac32\\\frac32&9\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I would prefer the OP to do at least something by himself...